# cerrar y abrir un menú en html con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

cuando al darle clic al icono se despliegue el menú y al darle otra vez se oculte y si le doy clic afuera se oculta, el problema en mi código es cuando  al darle clic afuera se oculta y hasta ahí bien pero si quiero darle otra vez clic al icono le tengo que dar doble clic.¿como le hago para que no tenga que darle doble clic?

```
var mostrar = true;
function trespuntos(){
    if(mostrar==true){
        document.getElementById('desplegar_menu').style.visibility="visible";
        mostrar=false;

     }
    else
     {
        window.addEventListener("click", function(event){
            if(event.target !=true){
            document.getElementById('desplegar_menu').style.visibility="hidden"
            }
        },true);
       document.getElementById("desplegar_menu").style.visibility="hidden";
       mostrar=true;
     }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el HTML de tu página?

Comment: Podrías utilizar el método `toggle()` de jQuery, lo que te permitiría de una muy simple de mostrar y ocultar los elementos que quieras de tú HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
var mostrar = true;

function trespuntos(){
    if(mostrar==true){
        document.getElementById('desplegar_menu').style.visibility="visible";
        mostrar=false;
    }
    else
   {
        document.getElementById("desplegar_menu").style.visibility="hidden";
        mostrar=true;
   }
}

window.addEventListener("click", function(event){
   if(event.target !=true){
      document.getElementById('desplegar_menu').style.visibility="hidden"
      mostrar = true;
    }
},true);
```